# IBM Worklight 6.1 - What symbol is this?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, eclipse-juno

I'm using IBM worklight 6.1 and eclipse Juno for my mobile app project. This is a first time I got this kind of symbol on my eclipse. Can I know what symbol is this?

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The markings overlayed on the folder and file icons are called `decorators`. The ones depicted in your screen shot are not coming from Worklight.

- The decorator overlayed on the folder icon is called `staged` or `partially-staged`.
  http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide/State#Label_Decorations

  > **staged** - The resource has changes which are added to the index. Not
  >   that adding to the index is possible at the moment only on the commit
  >   dialog on the context menu of a resource.
  >   **partially-staged** - The resource has changes which are added to the index and additionally changes in the working tree that are neither in the index nor in the
  >   repository.
- The decorator overlayed on the files icon is called `added`.
  http://www.rorycullen.com/blog/2009/07/guide-to-subclipse-decorator-icons/

  > The “**plus**” sign indicates that this is a new file that did not exist
  >   before.

You may have enabled some source control plug-in in your Eclipse installation.
In any case, not related to Worklight.